# Request: Reduce the number of votes to close & reopen questions from 5 to 3 for Photo-SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

In light of the reduced activity on this site from, say, 5–10 years ago, it seems like the Review Queues don't receive as much love and attention as they used to. This is especially obvious in the Close Votes (and much less frequently, Reopen Votes).

A question currently needs 5 votes to close it, whether it's off-topic, a duplicate, unclear, etc. Lately I've noticed that for the most part, questions that clearly should be closed that are in the Close Vote queue take a week or two to get enough votes to close. Even then, one of the mods are often the 5th vote.

I believe that Photo-SE no longer has enough active users to support the 5 votes for Close and Reopen. 3 votes are adequate to have enough users with the "Vote to Close" privilege.

Edit: This is something that was [tested on multiple Stack sites a couple years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/175991). If we have clear support to change from 5 to 3, the Photo-SE mods can ask SE to make the change for our site.

Comment: SE Community Mods: see the conversation in the Photography Mods chat room; this is something we want to move forward with. Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: Hey folks, I did a quick review and see no issues here. I've made this change.

Comment: @Slate Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

### Yes – the number of close & reopen votes should be reduced to 3

Answer (score 2):

### No – the number of close & reopen votes should stay at 5